# Can't use pop in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, bridging-header, facebook-pop

I'm using Xcode 8 and both `Swift` and `Objective-C` in my code. Recently, I updated my Xcode from 7.3.1 to 8 and converted Swift syntax to Swift 3. Then I got this error:

[image]

1. 'pop/POP.h' file not found.
2. failed to import bridging header
3. also some problem about pop

I'm sure that my bridging header file is at right position, and the path in Build Settings is right. I use cocoapods to install pop. Cocoapods version is 1.1.0.rc.2, pop version is 1.0.9. I think there is some problem about pop. But I don't know what happened to it. Can someone help me?